# Find one word and replace it with a list in VS code

Tags: list, visual-studio-code, replace, automation

I'm looking for a way to find one character (for example "#" ) and replace it with a list in Visual studio code.

The list would be

```
https:/example/12323.jpg
https:/example/224342.jpg
https:/example/31213.jpg
....
....
....
....
+ 500 more


For example:

    

            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="#">
            </div>

            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="#">
            </div>

            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="#">
            </div>

+500 more

    
# To be replaced by elements on my list like this:
    


            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="https:/example/12323.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="https:/example/224342.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="gg-element">
                <img src="https:/example/31213.jpg">
            </div>
```

Is there any way to do that in VS code with the find and replace feature and regular expression maybe?

Thanks in advance.